# Android request Web Service error: without a valid action parameter

Tags: android, web-services, server

Today I do the test about Android client request the server with web service.But this reason: "result = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();"is default.The Errors are:

**Unable to handle request without a valid action parameter.Please supply a 
valid soap action.**

The Client Code:

```js
package com.example.helloworld_webservicewithksoap;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.SoapFault;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpResponseException;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 
 TextView tvMessage;
 final String METHOD_HELLO_WORLD = "HelloWorld"; 
// final String METHOD_CheckInLockPark = "checkin_lockpark";
 
 //服务器链接
 final String WEB_SERVICE_URL = "http://120.24.254.42:802/OperData.asmx";
 final String Namespace = "http://tempuri.org";//命名空间
    
 Button button1;

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  
  initBtn();
  initTv();
  
 }
 
 private void  initTv(){
  
  tvMessage = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.tvMessage);
  
 }

 private void initBtn(){
  
  button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.helloworldbutton);
  button1.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {
    
    Map<String, String> values = new HashMap<String, String>();
    values.put("msg", "这是Android手机发出的信息");
    Request(METHOD_HELLO_WORLD);
    
   }
   
  });
  
 }
 
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
  return true;
  
 }

 /**
  * 调用WebService
  * 
  * @return WebService的返回值
  * 
  */
 public String CallWebService(String MethodName, Map<String, String> Params) {
  
  // 1、指定webservice的命名空间和调用的方法名
  SoapObject request = new SoapObject(Namespace, MethodName);
  
  // 2、设置调用方法的参数值，如果没有参数，可以省略，
  if (Params != null) {
   
   Iterator iter = Params.entrySet().iterator();
   
   while ( iter.hasNext() ) {
    
    Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) iter.next();
    request.addProperty( (String) entry.getKey(),
      (String) entry.getValue() );
    
   }
   
  }
  
  // 3、生成调用Webservice方法的SOAP请求信息。该信息由SoapSerializationEnvelope对象描述
  SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
    SoapEnvelope.VER12);
  envelope.bodyOut = request;
  // c#写的应用程序必须加上这句
  
  envelope.dotNet = true;
  HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(WEB_SERVICE_URL);
  
  // 使用call方法调用WebService方法
  
  try {
   
   ht.call(null, envelope);
   
  } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
   
   Log.e("----HttpResponseException异常---", e.getMessage());
   e.printStackTrace();
   
   
  } catch (IOException e) {
   
   Log.e("----IOException异常---", e.getMessage());
   e.printStackTrace();
   
  } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
   
   Log.e("----XmlPullParserException异常---", e.getMessage());
   e.printStackTrace();
   
  }
  
  try {
   
   final SoapPrimitive result = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
   
   if (result != null) {
    
    Log.d("----收到的回复----", result.toString());
    return result.toString();
    
   }
   

  } catch (SoapFault e) {
   
   Log.e("----发生错误---", e.getMessage());
   e.printStackTrace();
   
  }
  return null;
 }
 
 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  
  int id = item.getItemId();
  if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
   return true;
  }
  return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  
 }
 
 /**
  * 执行异步任务
  * 
  * @param params
  *            方法名+参数列表（哈希表形式）
  */
 public void Request( Object... params) {
  
  new AsyncTask<Object, Object, String>() {

   @Override
   protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {
    
                System.out.println("Params的长度"+params.length);
                
    if (params != null && params.length == 2) {
     
     return CallWebService( (String) params[0],
       (Map<String, String>) params[1] );
     
    } else if (params != null && params.length == 1) {
     
     return CallWebService((String) params[0], null);
     
    } else {
     
     return null;
     
    }
    
   }

   protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    
    if (result != null) {
     
     tvMessage.setText("服务器回复的信息 : " + result);
     
    }
    
   };

  }.execute(params);
 
 }
 
}
```

The Server Code:

```js
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using ConcSoft.Database;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections;

namespace ECM
{
     
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // 若要允许使用 ASP.NET AJAX 从脚本中调用此 Web 服务，请取消对下行的注释。
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class OperData : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }

     
}
```

Comment: I solve my peoblem.The answer:  1: insert " private static final String HelloWorld_SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/HelloWorld";"    2: instead of  "ht.call( null, envelope);" with "ht.call( HelloWorld_SOAP_ACTION, envelope);"